# Prevent reloading a website after sweetalert

Tags: javascript, php, alert, sweetalert2

On a web page there is a table with a few rows. In each line there is a button that triggers a Javascript function:

PHP/HTML:

```
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
echo "<button type='submit' name='test' value=".$row[4]." class='attest btn btn-info btn-round btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-neutral' data-original-title='Test'><i class='now-ui-icons files_single-copy-04'></i></button>";
echo "</form>";
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])) 
{
    $file="/files/".$_POST['test'].".jpg";
    $caption="Image: ".$_POST['test'];

    if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file)) 
        {
            echo"<body onload='showtest()'>";
        } 
    else 
        {

            echo"<body onload='notest()'>";
        }
}
```

JS:

```
function showtest()
{
 swal({
  title: 'Image',
  text: <?php echo json_encode($caption); ?>,
  imageUrl: <?php echo json_encode($file); ?>,
  imageWidth: 400,
  imageAlt: 'Image',
})
}

function noattest()
{
swal({
  title: 'Image',
  text: "There is no image.",
  icon: 'warning',
})
}
```

A dialog is then displayed using Sweetalert2. The problem is that the table contains so many records that the web page must be scrolled. As a result, the alert is displayed correctly, but the web page "scrolls up again"/reloads. This is very annoying, because you have to search for the right row in the table again.

Is there a solution so that the web page does not jump to the top?

Comment: Your site refreshes because you are using html forms that have to submit to send data to your back-end. This is generally not done anymore for this very reason. You will need to leverage `ajax` or something similar to send data using javascript instead.

Comment: save the scroll position  to localStorage right before submitting the form then and when page first loads have it scroll to the saved position.